# Using vuex with Vue 3

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Last year I spent some time learning Vue 2.  I really enjoyed the framework but did not move forward with a project.  I now have time for a project but I'd like to use Vue 3 with the composition API.  I'll be using Firebase as the backend.  I've seen conflicting techniques on whether or not to use Vuex.

For example, I'd like to store a "currentUser" object in global state that can be accessed from any component in the app.  Normally, it would be done using Vuex.  I'd have a getter to return the object, an async action to get the data from firebase and a mutation to set the state.

However, I've seen several Vue 3 code examples that do not use Vuex at all, instead they do something like this to get/set a currentUser in an app wherever it is needed for example in a navbar component.

composables/getUser.js

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

// refs
const user = ref(firebase.auth().currentUser)

// auth changes
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(_user => {
  console.log('User state change. Current user is:', _user)
  user.value = _user
});

const getUser = () => {
  return { user } 
}

export default getUser
```

With this little bit of code above, I'm able to import getUser.js and access the currently logged in user using code like this.  Also, the user object is now reactive:

```
<script>
import getUser from '../composables/getUser'

export default {
  setup() {
    const { user } = getUser()
    return { user }
  }
}
</script>
```

It seems I can use these little functions to get data from db directly without the need to use the Vuex pattern, which I find to be a bit more complicated.

So, my question is - if I'm starting a new Vue 3 project, is it ok to create "composable" functions to get/set data and import them into my components instead of using Vuex?  Are there any downsides to this method?  Or should I just stick with Vuex?

Comment: Simple answer: try to not use a framework at all. Use Snabbdom, write a simple router. Tell your server what user role and what page they are looking at. Focus on business logic on server side. Do not "fetch" data. Do not create "APIs". Provide a collection of business abstractions (a collection of collections) on each significant navigation change (or a details toggle). Frameworks are there to waste time, not to save. Make sure you do write a server endpoint per each pair "Route+Role".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - You don't need it.

Long answer - It depends.

It depends mostly on your app and how often do you use "currentUser" data inside your components. If it's in 2 or more components, how often do you want to perform actually fetching from backend?

Once on app-init/login or every time each component mounts?

(probably once)
Does it need to be reactive? If yes - then you'll probably use centralized data pattern, your own or a library. Taken that into consideration it's probably more simple to just use Vuex.